# Does anyone happen to know what font this is?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Does anyone happen to know what font this is? I’ve tried a few ways to identify but am getting stuck. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hi @mcoopgraphics! We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font-identification questions, Please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 3):

- As long as the two characters "o" are different, it's unlikely to be
  a font.
- It's a corporate image of a [tv channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_TV), which accentuates the
  probability that it's a custom typeface

Look for similar fonts making an advanced search at [myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/search/marker/fonts/) using "*marker*"

Or Google Images with *[marker fonts](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1854&bih=1087&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=0N3wXNmzE5KAad3UpRA&q=marker%20fonts&oq=marker%20fonts&gs_l=img.3..0j0i7i30j0i8i7i30j0i5i30l3j0i8i30j0i24l3.9311.10433..10805...0.0..0.70.392.6......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0i7i5i30.hnhujkqyuMw)*

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you Danielillo. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @mcoopgraphics You should "accept" any answer that answered your question by clicking the checkbox next to the answer. Doing so will give reputation to both you and the answerer